# How to format date in php like August 2020

Tags: php, laravel, date

I'm trying to format date in php laravel and i don't know how format it in long format way, i know that i can use: **now()->format('M Y')** , but it produces short month format **Aug 2020** , so i need the way to get **August 2020** , Then how can i get it that to work?

```php
{{ now()->format('M Y') }}
```

Comment: Carbon docs: [Common Formats](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats)

Comment: The basic PHP documentation for formatting dates is here https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php
Have a look through that and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.
`now()->format('F Y')`

I think everything you need is here...
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php